# Issue in Dynamically Add Select Element In J Query Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am adding select element dynamically on the change event of another select when I first click on static select then dynamically Select shown on page with all of its options but when I again select different value from static select the dynamic select shown on page but with no options?
[Here is my demo page](http://engineers-web.com/F09/demo/#addExercise)

Comment: Please post some code here. Explain how do you append them dynamically. Do you use ajax or php...etc what version of jquery and jquery mobile are being used.

Comment: Using ajax
And by @Tolis answer now it works fine Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add `$('#exerciseList-dialog').remove();` inside the loadExerciseList function.

Basically this line removes the dialog from DOM when you change category.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot @Tolis it works for me
But I wounder how it works?
Pleas give me some explanation

Comment: @BluAngel Use firebug to examine the DOM structure. You will see that multiple dialogs with the same id `exerciseList-dialog` were added in DOM. That was the error cause.